# I'cant Download Image of post from Facebook

Tags: image, facebook, download

I use the api graph and obtain an image the type:
https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/27972193_10209727361415594_5326795209597866457_n.jpg?oh=680574d073b0e54d60ed86f9143b05f0&oe=5B1CC7DD

The, I use this code por download the image:

```
$link_curl = curl_init($image);
curl_setopt($link_curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$bytes_image = curl_exec($link_curl);
curl_close($link_curl);

$image_name=date("YmdHis")."jpg";

$file = fopen( $directory_local . $image_name,'w'); 
fwrite($file,$bytes_imagen); 
fclose($file);
```

The result is a file empty.
Help Please

Comment: Where did you get the URL from?

Comment: api graph the facebook

    1) $response = 
    $fb->get('/me/feedhttps://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/me/feed?
    fields=id,message,picture', $accessToken);
        
    2) $get_data = $response->getDecodedBody(); 

    3) $image=$get_data['data'][$i]['picture'];

(the value of $imagen is --> https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/27972193_10209727361415594_5326795209597866457_n.jpg?oh=680574d073b0e54d60ed86f9143b05f0&oe=5B1CC7DD